# Why dynamic field is added even though dynamic is set to strict in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set dynamic property to "strict" for my fields. But when I update using POST _update api, a dynamic field is added.

**Mapping is as follows:**

```
{
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
        "title": {
             "type": "keyword"
         },
         "track": {
             "properties": {
                  "date": {
                     "type": "date"
                  }
              }
          }
    }
}
```

**POST _update query :**

```
{
    "doc": {
        "track.date": "2004-08-14"
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
   "title": "some-title",
   "track": {
        "date" : "2020-04-12:00:00:00"
    },
    "track.date":"2004-08-14"
}
```

Why is the new field "track.date" created?
Shouldn't the POST update give an error instead of updating the above field?

Comment: Can you provide the exact steps you're doing? I suspect something's missing there.

Comment: I created index with the mapping given, inserted data and updated an entry using the given update api.

Answer (score 0):

I believe dynamic mapping only affects *new* fields, not updates.
So i'd say this is the expected behaviour : `track.date` is a valid field present in the indice's mapping, so nothing crashes.

Edit : i could not find any way to explicitly prevent document updates, but you *can* disable the `_source` field, which will, as a side-effect, disable document updates. Please read [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) before doing so, though.

Edit 2: I have created a new topic [on the forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elastic-stack/elasticsearch/6) to confirm this is a bug.

It seems that elasticsearch considers`"field1.field2": "12"` and

```
"field1": {
   "field2": "12"
}
```

to have the exact same mapping.
The query :

```
PUT /test2
{
   "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
         "field1.field2": {"type": "text"}
      }
   }
}
```

Creates an indice with the following mapping (query'd via `GET /test2/_mappings`) :

```
{
   "test2": {
      "mappings": {
         "dynamic": "strict",
         "properties": {
            "field1": {
               "properties": {
                  "field2": {
                     "type": "text"
}}}}}}} // collapsed
```

But updating (and/or) indexing documents treats both syntax differently :

```
POST /test2/_doc/0
{
   "doc": {
      "field1": {
         "field2": "0"
}}}
```

yields (query'd via `GET test2/_search`): `"field1": {"field2":"0"}`

whereas

```
POST /test2/_doc/0
{
   "doc": {
      "field1.field2": "1"
}}
```

yields `"field1.field2": "1"`

Comment: I meant a new field "track.date" was created. Is that supposed to happen? I have edited the question.

Comment: @RAJEESHPM i have updated my answer accordingly. Sadly it became a quite huge answer, if you see how formatting could be improved please do tell me about it.